# bootstrap 3.4.1 navbar link show up and work properly in mobile firefox but do not work in mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Visual studio and ASP.net to build a web page.

My code:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
</head>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="" src="~/resources/favicon.ico"></a><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">ASTRO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/img">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/whatsup">Tonight's Sky</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap link I'm using:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I've tried the latest bootstrap version 5.1.3 with no luck.

As I said in the header, Works fine in the mobile Firefox but all I get mobile Chrome browser is the Navbar and the "ASTRO" link which works the other links in the list don't show. And when I click on the 3 bars button nothing happens.

Does Chrome need some special settings?

Thanks
Nor

Comment: I don't see it working in Firefox either.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to include jQuery and Bootstrap `.js` files since the button uses JavaScript:

Updated code:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="" src="~/resources/favicon.ico"></a><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">ASTRO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/img">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/whatsup">Tonight's Sky</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks much for that. Yup adding the script links did the trick.